# Prisma ORM how to orderBy counted nested relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Im trying to orderBy a nested relationship count in prisma.  For instance:  you have an `Author` object which refers to `Post`s and each `Post` refers to `Comment`s.

```
model Post {
  id    String @id
  title String

  author   Author
  comments Comment[]  
}

model Author {
  id   String @id
  name String

  posts Post[]
}

model Comment {
  id      String @id
  content String

  post Post
}
```

I want to fetch `Author`s but orderBy the total number of `Comment`s on all of their `Post`s.  I know this example is a little odd, but that is what I need to accomplish.

**I want something like this:**

```
prisma.author.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    posts: {
      _count: {
        sum: 'comments'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It is possible to do this:

`prisma.author.findMany({ orderBy: { posts: { _count: "desc" }}})`

But that only sorts the authors by their number of posts.  I want to sort by their number of comments and I'm not seeing how that is possible.

Comment: According to my knowledge, there's no other way than to use `$queryRaw` right now. I'm fighting with the same problem and I'm also dealing with a complex query so I don't want to switch to `$queryRaw`. I'll post an answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd have to use `prisma.$queryRaw` to get this. `$queryRaw` allows you to write raw queries to the DB (for example: `` const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User` `` ).

[More in the official Prisma documentation for `$queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access).

Comment: Yes, that can be done for anything, but its not "prisma", its SQL.  And we cant just replace our entire complicated query with raw SQL